# ionic tabs broke Swipe to go back function

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my project I have view with some tabs, on that view swipe to go back function didn't work compare to android physical button whick works correctly. On every other view in my ionic project swipe to go back works perfectly, any ideas what's wrong ?

Comment: I guess thats because its firing tab change event when you try to swipe back.

Comment: @HardikVaghani How can I disable this event ?

Comment: `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);` this should do it.

Comment: @HardikVaghani unfortunately didn't work for me. I'm using ion-tab instead of ion-slide-box

Comment: Try controlling gesture to go back on each tab. I guess there is no delegate available for ion-tab.

Comment: Did u get any solution for this issue